# Google maps js api v3: StreetView Panorama finished loading?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I'm having some trouble with my streetview. I want to show the streetview only after it finishes loading, so that the gray colour is not displayed. I searched the api, but I don't think there's any events that I can make use of: [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanorama)

Is there any way (including non official ways) to show the streetview AFTER it's fully loaded? Thanks!

Comment: Does it work correctly if you load the API synchronously?

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    ....

    window.onload = initialize();

Comment: I think it should work. check the following link

http://jsfiddle.net/wK5Hq/23/

Comment: @vinod_vh: You realize that your example becomes gray before the streetview is showed for half a second?

Comment: @DavidMulder u want to show the streetview only after it finishes loading, but before loading that u have to show some background color in that place right..?

Comment: Well, it's a general question for any event that will trigger once it's loaded, so in my case I want to show an overlay over it, other people might want to keep the map visible with only a loader visible and show the Streetview once it finishes loading. This question received around 800 views already, so that's why I decided to put a bounty on this question as it seems I am not the only one who wants to do this.

Comment: the street view itself is basically a canvas. I didnt test myself. but theoretically you can do null check before you show your content

Comment: @D.J ... hmm~ That might be actually a pretty cool idea, the canvas is transparent indeed, so looping over the pixels till no pixels are transparent anymore would work (possibly only checking pixels on a 50x50 grid)... still hoping for a more efficient solution, *but* it would be a possible solution indeed.

Answer (score 1):

hiding and making the div visible after map is loaded should do the trick ...

like this

```
<div id="pano" style="position:absolute; left:410px; top: 8px; width: 400px; height: 300px;visibility:hidden;"></div>

<script> google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load',initialize);
setTimeout('showPano()',1000);
function showPano(){
document.getElementById('pano').style.visibility='visible';}
</script>
```

hope it helped you

Answer (score 0):

I did some test (edited example of vinod_vh, see http://jsfiddle.net/nDwSC/2/) and found out, that the `links_changed` event is the last one launched:

> 1. červen 2013 17:48:28.775 ===== CLICK OCCURRED ===== /nDwSC/2/show/ (line 210)
> 2. červen 2013 17:48:28.780 resize /nDwSC/2/show/ (line 170)
> 3. červen 2013 17:48:28.843 zoom_changed /nDwSC/2/show/ (line 173)
> 4. červen 2013 17:48:29.603 pano_changed /nDwSC/2/show/ (line 158)
> 5. červen 2013 17:48:29.622 position_changed /nDwSC/2/show/ (line 161)
> 6. červen 2013 17:48:29.634 links changed

So you might actually want to use this event! It will be launched also in different contexts, but you can handle this by having some flag variable, which will be set when you click the button, and tested in the handler, with possible timeout.

So, what you should do:

1. hide your streetview; but dont use `display: none`, use the trick
   with off-left hiding technique as in jQuery UI < 1.9 (for new
   versions [there is it doesn't work
   unfortunately](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-tabs-1-10-off-left-hiding-of-charts-and-maps):

   `.hide { 
           position: absolute !important;
           left: -10000px !important;
       }`

   keep the hidden frame of the same dimensions as the resultant one!
2. handle the `links_changed` event - remove the `hide` class, and do resize of the map.

If you see that `links_changed` event is fired too early, there's no other possibility to do this cleanly by handling events. [You cannot even use the map `idle` event](http://jsfiddle.net/nDwSC/4/) (and `idle` event for `google.maps.StreetViewPanorama` doesn't exist). So the last resort is probably to use some fixed timeout - that works perfectly!

Comment: Although your approach definitely sounds nice, when executed practically it becomes visible that the links_changed is fired faar to early: http://jsfiddle.net/fLTEm/1/embedded/result/ (the dark overlay dissapears when the event is triggered)

Comment: @DavidMulder - well, I tested all available events and apparently none works. Research sometimes ends in a dead-end, but this is also a result - **now we can honestly conclude there's no clean solution to this problem**. You have to set some fixed timeout for that.

Comment: That's why the question asked for unofficial ways as well. The checking of the canvas for colour data didn't work out either, as the canvas gets tainted...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load panorama after loaded, for that you may use iframe and with that you can have wrapper with AJAX loader, that will not change until the map loaded, (ready state ==4),( or one more ajax loader wrapper with some global variable as flag to know the ready state.., Note: this is unstable idea, but works with some browsers)

That will be easy way, in API, if you want to do that,

refer event listeners ,

else

[options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanoramaOptions) have one option in documentation,

i.e.

visible :: boolean  ::  If true, the Street View panorama is visible on load.

I hope this will make things easy on your side..

I hope I have answered in context to your actual requirements..

Comment: the problem is that the StreetView is loaded asynchronously by javascript... so all these events will be actualy fired *before* the StreetView is loaded.